# Can't find the audio files which I received via WhatsApp on my Nokia Lumia 520

Tags: lumia, whatsapp

The audio files I received via WhatsApp are seen nowhere on my phone. I don't use an external memory card, so I guess the audio files will be saved in the internal memory. But I cant find them anywhere. Where should I search for these files? Actually i wanted to delete these audio files if it had been saved in my phone... The images and videos are found in the folder named whats app in the gallery. But the audio files are nowhere seen..

Answer (score 0):

Look in Whatsapp in Chats at the Person, who sent it to you. Open, Menu, Info, Media. There are all Files that he sent to you. It works for my Lumia 920. (Sorry for my bad English)
Mario

Comment: but how to export them to a PC